# Why does std::fstream set the EOF bit the way it does?

Tags: c++, iostream, library-design

I recently ran into a problem caused by using fstream::eof(). I read the following line from [here](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/io/eof):

> The function eof() returns true if the end of the associated input file has been reached, false otherwise.

and (mistakenly) assumed this meant that if I used fstream::read() and read past the end of the file, the function eof() would tell me. So I did something like this (very generalized):

```
for(int i = 0; i < max && !file.eof(); i++)
{
     file.read(mything, sizeof(mything));
}
```

The problem came because of what is explained later on the page linked above (which I failed to read initially, thanks to the misleading first paragraph):

> Conversely, the stream does not go into EOF state if there happens to be any whitespace after the last token, but trying to read another token will still fail. Therefore, the EOF flag cannot be used as a test in a loop intended to read all stream contents until EOF. Instead, one should check for the fail condition after an attempt to read.

So I changed, and now my loop checks against file.fail() rather than file.eof(), and I understand HOW eof() works. My question is, why does it work that way? Are there situations where this is desirable? It seems to me that once you've passed EOF, you've passed EOF and eof() should return true.

**UPDATE**
Thanks for the responses, I think I've got it. The only operation I'm performing is read(), and I immediately check for fail(), so I think I'm okay. Now, my question is, what *would* I use eof() for?

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < max && file.read(mything, sizeof(mything)); i++) {}

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because this way it can detect `EOF` without knowing how large the file is. All it has to do is simply attempt to read and if the read is short (but not an error), then you have reached the end of the file.

This mirrors the functionality of the `read` system call, which file IO typically ends up calling (win32 stuff may call `ReadFile` but I believe that the functionality is similar).

From the `read` manpage "RETURN VALUE" section (emphasis added):

> On success, the number of bytes read
>   is returned **(zero indicates end of
>   file)**, and the file position is
>   advanced by this number. It is not an
>   error if this number is smaller than
>   the number of bytes requested; this
>   may happen for example because fewer
>   bytes are actually available right now
>   (maybe because we were close to
>   end-of-file, or because we are reading
>   from a pipe, or from a terminal), or
>   because read() was interrupted by a
>   signal. On error, -1 is returned, and
>   errno is set appropriately. In this
>   case it is left unspecified whether
>   the file position (if any) changes.

BTW: a good way to write what you wanted would be like this:

```
T something;
while(file.read(something, sizeof(something))) {
    // process your 'something'
}
```

this works because `file.read` (like many members of iostream) return a reference to the iostream itself. All of which have an operator overloaded to allow testing the stream state. Similarly to read from `std::cin`, `while(std::cin >> x) { ... }` works as well.

**EDIT:** you should know that testing vs. fail can be equally wrong for the same reason. From the page you linked to `fail()` returns if **the previous operation failed.** Which means you need to perform a read or other relevant operation before testing it.

Comment: I tried the suggested while loop but noticed that the body of the loop will not be performed, when fewer bytes read than the size of `something`.

Comment: @ChristianAmmer correct, this code will process **whole** objects. If you want to process things like lines of strings, or similar, I'd recommend a slightly different, but very similar loop: https://godbolt.org/z/Y3dMev

Answer (score 0):

```
int n;
std::cin >> n >> std::stripws;
```

fixes this problem.  at that point you can use either .good() or .eof().
I like to use .good(), since if there is a bad disk block, .good() will detect it.  but that's me.  .eof() will not, you will also have to add .fail() || .bad().

I just found this out after some hard study about the problem of eating whitespace.  I was going to propose an ECO to iostream and ifstream, and lo and behold, it's already been done. :-D