# Difficulty using file.seekg() (C++)

Tags: c++, file, eof, seekg

The following code only prints the file once:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("in", ios::binary);
    char c;

    while (infile.get(c))
    {
        cout << c;
    }

    infile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    infile.clear();

    while (infile.get(c))
    {
            cout << c;
    }
    infile.close(); 
    return 0;
}
```

I assume it has something to do with the eof flag after running through the file, but I don't know how to fix that.

Cheers.

Comment: NO NO NO `while (!infile.eof())` Do NOT do this!!  Use `while(infile >> c) { //do stuff with c }` instead.

Comment: @TonyTheLion I'm not sure you can use `operator>>` with a binary file, but your comment is still a step in the right direction. What I've used for reading binary files is `while( infile.read( &c, 1 ) { ... }` Also, James, the reason nothing is printed the second time if you use `infile.good()` is because some flag is being set by the first loop. Try calling `infile.clear()` before starting the second loop.

Comment: Possible indirect duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039667/why-does-stdfstream-set-the-eof-bit-the-way-it-does

Comment: @TonyTheLion Or `while ( infile.get( c ) )`.  Or even `int c = infile.get(); while ( c != EOF ) { ... ; c = infile.get(); }`.

Comment: @Praetorian Why shouldn't you be able to use the `>>` with a file opened in binary mode (which isn't necessarily a binary file).

Comment: @JamesKanze I didn't say you couldn't, just that I didn't know if you could. I've just never used it with a file in binary mode.

Comment: @Praetorian Interesting.  Unless I'm using `>>` and `<<`, I usually won't bother with iostream.  (I will occasionally use an `istream` for character input, just using `get`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

First, you don't check that `infile.get()` succeeds before using
its results, ever.  And you are using `infile.good()` to control
one loop, and `infile.eof()` to control another: `infile.eof()`
isn't useful until you know that the input has failed, and
`infile.good()` is never really useful.  Just use `while
( infile.get( c ) )` for both loops.

Second, as you say, you never reset the "error" that caused you
to finish the first loop.  Once you've encountered the end of
file (and `infile.get( c )` has failed), you need to call
`infile.clear()` before doing anything else.

Finally, of course, you fail to check whether you successfully
opened the file, and whether the `seekg` succeeded.  And you
generally don't have to close an input file; it will be closed
automatically when it goes out of scope.  (On the other hand,
you *should* either close or flush `std::cout`, and verify that
it is still OK afterwards.  Returning `0` when you've failed to
write all of the data is a serious error in my book.)

Comment: (As far as I can tell) edited the code to the suggestions, it still doesn't print the second time around.

Comment: Also how exactly would you check whether seekg() 'worked'? By using tellg()?

(If so it's returning -1, which I guess means seekg() isn't working, in which case, why?)

Comment: @JamesJenkinson The same way you tell if anything you do on an istream or an ostream worked: treat the stream as if it were a boolean; if it evaluates `true`, there have been no errors to date.

Comment: @JamesJenkinson You have to do the `clear()` _before_ the seek.  A general rule with istream and ostream: errors are sticky.  And trying to read beyond the end of file is an "error" (since the read didn't succeed).